# Failing task since test cases were expected but none were found

Tags: testing, mule, bamboo, munit

I have a Bamboo job for mulesoft code, with steps as code checkout, build, test which generates coverage report, deploy.
Test step is failing with message 'Failing task since test cases were expected but none were found.' and coverage report is generated in specific path.
When I remove the specific path, job is success but coverage is not generated.
I tried enabling 'maven return code', which makes the job success, but can't see coverage report.

1. Give the path **/target/*, enable maven return code - job success, coverage not generated
2. Give the path **/target/*, disable maven return code - job failed, coverage generated

Comment: I'm trying to capture the test coverage report in summary.html

Answer (score 1):

This should be very late answer but I got same issue with Java + Maven + TestNG + Bamboo and resolved with the respective **bamboo task**

The below option should be unchecked
**The build will produce test results - Uncheck**

[Maven task configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0vzl.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix, I had to upgrade munit plugin to higher version ! This fixed the issue !